# LAPACK - singular matrices - what does the positive integer info mean?

Tags: lapack, matrix

please can you help me with my code - I use Lapack to solve complex matrix (quite biq) and do it in two steps: I call `zgetrf` (LU factorization) and then `zgetrs` (solving system).
But the `info` value for `zgetrf` is not zero - `zgetrf` fails to factorize the matrix. The `info` value is 2. In the manual of Intel MKL (I use Lapack from these) they write:

> `info`   INTEGER.
>
> If `info=0`, the execution is successful.
>
> If `info = -i`,
>   the i-th parameter had an illegal value.
>
> If `info = i`, $u_{ii}$ is 0. The
>   factorization has been completed, but $U$ is exactly singular. Division
>   by 0 will occur if you use the factor $U$ for solving a system of linear
>   equations.

So I understand my matrix is somehow singular. But what does the number say - if my info=2 then the second line in my matrix is linear dependent? Or something like that?
Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: nothing more than $U_{ii} = 0$, i.e. that your *computed* $U$ factorization is exactly singular.

`xGETRF` is not safe as a rank revealing factorization, so I would not draw any conclusion, apart from the fact that $A$ is ill-conditioned and no solution to $Ax=b$ can be safely computed. Information on rank and null space should be derived (if desired) by other decompositions, eg. $QR$.

Answer (score 3):

If you compute the LU factorization of an $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$, then you'll end up with

$PA=LU$

where $P$ is a permutation matrix, $L$ is lower triangular and nonsingular, and $U$ is upper triangular.  If $A$ happens to singular then the LAPACK routine will produce a $U$ matrix that is singular.  The only way that an upper triangular matrix can be singular is to have a diagonal entry which is 0 (the determinant of $U$ is the product of its diagonal entries.)  The info value returned by the LAPACK routine tells you the row/column of the first 0 on the diagonal of $U$.

You could use this information (for example) to find a nonzero vector $\hat{x}$ such that $U\hat{x}=0$.  Suppose that info is $k$.  Then let $\hat{x}_{j}=0$ for $j=n, n-1, \ldots, k+1$.  Let $\hat{x}_{k}=1$.  Then use back substitution to find $\hat{x}_{k-1}, \hat{x}_{k-2}, \ldots, \hat{x}_{1}$.

Then $LU\hat{x}=0$, so $\hat{x}$ is in the null space of $PA$.