# lapack singular matrix

Tags: lapack, matrix

I'd like to find a condition that allows me to determine if a matrix is invertible or not. naively, I computed the determinant to see if it was zero. but then I realized that even for very small values (1e-100), lapack is still able to find an invert matrix.

I read [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5192/lapack-singular-matrixes-what-does-the-positive-integer-info-mean) that a $QR$ factorization can be used to compute the rank of a matrix.

Is a $QR$ factorization the best way to check if a matrix is invertible? will it take into account the numerical errors ? is there a more efficient way ?

I also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974349/computing-the-reciprocal-condition-number-with-lapack-i-e-rcondx) that gives a reciprocal condition number $\kappa$. What does this number mean ? I know that if $\kappa=\infty$ then the matrix is singular ! But what is the cutoff, what is $\infty$ for a computer ?

Comment: For rank estimation/measuring closeness to singularity, in the prescence of fuzzy data or roundoff, the singular value decomposition is probably the most reliable calculation. Lapack provides routines to compute it (dgesvd, for instance). Wikipedia page has an SVD page, see the subsections regarding "Range, null space and rank" and "Low-rank matrix approximation". Golub and van Loan have good material as well, see section 2.5 entitled "Orthogonality and the SVD" (it deals with the intepretation of the SVD, actually calculating it requires more machinery and appears much later in the book).

Comment: The condition number (ratio of largest to smallest singular values from the SVD) is normally used as a measure of closeness to singularity.  For double precision matrices, any condition number bigger than 1.0e15 is effectively singular just due to the limits of double precision floating point.  However, much smaller condition numbers can be problematic if the data in your problem are not very precise.

Comment: @rchilton1980 : what about the link that i put ? instead of a $SVD$ he uses $LU$ then compute $\kappa$ with another lapack subroutine... is $SVD$ really better ?

Comment: @BrianBorchers according to your experience, what is a good limit for $\kappa$? 1e-10 ?

Comment: Are you solving a system of equations that involves measured data?  If they're only accurate to one part in $10^4$, then your solutions will not be trustworthy as soon as the condition number reaches $10^4$.

Comment: LAPACK provides a condition number estimate along with the LU factorization, but this estimate is not very precise at all (in my experience, it can easily be off by a factor of 10 or more.)  However, it often doesn't matter exactly how big the condition number is (e.g. it's "way too large!") so this might be entirely adequate for your purposes.

Comment: @BrianBorchers : no i'm just trying to find the inverse of a matrix that is numerically created...

Comment: i did few tests with upper diagonal $3\times3$ matrices and i got strange results. if the matrix diagonal is  $(1,1,10^{-200})$ the the condition number that lapack gives me (with `dlange_` and `dgecon_`) is of the order of $10^{-200}$ which seems correct. but lapack is still able to find a correct inverse... why

Comment: The condition number provides an upper bound on the error in the computation of a solution to your system of equations (or the computation of an inverse) with respect to any noise on the right hand side or in the matrix elements.  It doesn't follow that you will necessarily see an error that large.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Sorry to come back with a question 10 months later but I'd like understand something. In practice, if what I want is simply to invert a matrix, by that I mean I'm not trying to solve $Ax=b$ in which case $Ax=b+\delta b$ may give very different results if $A$ is ill-conditioned, what is a good $\kappa$ ? You said earlier something about measured data, it seemed logic to me. In my case, it's a well know and precise matrix that I'm willing to invert and no experimental data are involved. So, does it mean that a pertinent $\kappa$ would be $\kappa\sim 10^{-15}<$double_precision ?

Comment: If your condition number is around $10^15$, then your matrix is effectively singular in double precision.  You might get lucky in computing an inverse in double precision (as in your example, where the matrix is simply diagonal), but you shouldnn't count on this.  If you have exact matrix elements (as for example in the Hilbert matrix) and are using some high precision floating point arithmetic, then might still be able to compute a reasonable inverse.

Answer (score -1):

LU factorization exists only if the matrix is invertible (Not LUP). A common way to do this in Lapack is to try to obtain the LU decomposition. Many Lapack libraries will throw you an info code, stating the reason of failure. If your matrix is not invertible LU decomposition output "info" will not be 0 and you can check this flag to decide if your matrix is invertible or not.

Comment: "LU factorization exists only if the matrix is invertible (Not LUP)". No. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is a LU decomposition.

Comment: You are right that it depends on singularities of principal minors, I skipped this part.

Comment: On the other hand, if matrix is symmetric, checking Cholesky decomposition the same way is an approach.